# Parameters from bat file to sql script not working

Tags: c#, sql, command-line

I have a C# application calling a bat file:

```
new string[] { branchName + ".Order", "Order.bak", "Order"}
var arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\"\"{1}\"\"{2}\"\"{3}\"", stringse[0], stringse[1], stringse[2], sqlPath + "\\");

           var psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(filename)
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                Arguments = arguments
            };
            Process createDBs = Process.Start(psi);
            System.IO.StreamReader myOutput = createDBs.StandardOutput;
            while (!createDBs.HasExited)
            {
                string output = myOutput.ReadToEnd();
                LogStep(output);
            }
```

The bat file looks like this:

```
@echo off

REM ************************************************
REM * RestoreDB script for use by Development Team *
REM ************************************************

@echo %1 %2 %3 %4

@echo Restore of database started...
SQLCMD -S (local) -d Master -i RestoreDB.sql -v varDatabaseName=%1 varDatabaseBackupFileName= %2 varLogicalName= %3 varSQLDataFolder= %4
@echo Restore of database finished...
pause
```

The Sql script looks receive these parameters like this:

SET @DatabaseName = N'$(varDatabaseName)'
   SET @DatabaseBackupFileName = N'$(varDatabaseBackupFileName)'
   SET @LogicalName = N'$(varLogicalName)'
   SET @SQLDataFolder = N'$(varSQLDataFolder)'
(Can't paste complete code due to security reasons)

Now my problem is that I don't think I'm passing the variables from bat to sql script correctly.
When calling the bat file out of C# it echo's the values
When calling the sql directly out of command prompt it works correctly, so I know my sql script is working:

```
SQLCMD -S (local) -d Master -i RestoreDB.sql -v varDatabaseName="Piet.Order.Test" varDatabaseBackupFileName="Order.bak" varLogicalName="Order" varSQLDataFolder="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"
```

I don't get any errors back to my C# application, so when running my application it just runs and calls the bat with parameters, the call from bat to sql seems to go wrong.Is it a format problem with my parameters. I tried single quotes '%1' and tried doubele quotes "%1", nothing seems to work.Can anybody shine some light.Any way maybe how I can retrieve the error that is happening with the call to sql

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a space between arguments

```
var arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"{3}\"", 
                stringse[0], stringse[1], stringse[2], sqlPath + "\\");
```

In these scenarios (debugging parameters) could be very useful to start the command processor and leave the console window open after the execution of the program

```
var arguments = String.Format("/K {4} \"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"{3}\"", 
                stringse[0], stringse[1], stringse[2], sqlPath + "\\", filename);
```

and call the command processor in the ProcessStartInfo

```
 var psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
```